# Inequivalence metrics generate same Borel $\sigma$-field.

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, weak-convergence, borel-sets, separable-spaces

I want to find an example of metric $d$ for $[0,1]$ so that $(d,[0,1])$ is a separable metric space; $d$ is not equivalent to usual metric, but the Borel $\sigma$-field is same as the usual one.

Here the term "equivalent" means topological equivalence of metric. I found this problem in the book by Patrick Billingsley, "Convergence of Measures", Problem 1.7.

Here is what I found in the StackExchange. [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383037/inequivalent-metrics-can-give-rise-to-the-same-class-of-borel-sets). But no answer was appropriate fits, so I asked again.

Comment: I don't understand your objection to the answer you link to. There are answers there that answer your question.